# Why is $\alpha^n\beta^m+\alpha^m\beta^n\le\alpha^s\beta^t+\alpha^t\beta^s$ if $(n,m)\preceq(s,t)$?

Tags: convex-analysis, products, convex-geometry

I've recently come across the following statement:
$$\alpha^n\beta^m+\alpha^m\beta^n\le\alpha^s\beta^t+\alpha^t\beta^s$$
for $\alpha,\beta\ge0$, $n,m,s,t\in\mathbb N_+$, $n+m=s+t$, and $(n,m)\preceq(s,t)$.
If anyone is interested (though it's not particularly relevant for the question itself), I found this stated in a slightly different form in [this paper](https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.41.1569), page 2, second column. They reference a [book on majorization](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387400877) in which I wasn't able to find an easy answer to this particular point (both paper and book are paywalled, sorry about that).

I can prove the case $n=m$ (see below), but I'm at a loss for the more general statement. What is an easy way to prove this?

Also, can this sort of statement be generalized to products of more than two numbers? The direct generalization would seem to be
$$\sum_{\sigma\in\mathcal P_N}\prod_{i=1}^N \alpha_{\sigma(i)}^{n_i}\le\sum_{\sigma\in\mathcal P_N}\prod_{i=1}^N \alpha_{\sigma(i)}^{m_i}$$
when $(n_1,..,n_N)\preceq(m_1,...,m_N)$.
If this holds, can the same technique used for the first statement be applied to this more general case?

---

For $n=m$ we write $s=\mu+\Delta, t=\mu-\Delta$, where $$\mu\equiv\frac{s+t}{2}=\frac{n+m}{2}=n.$$

We thus have
\begin{align}
(\alpha^n\beta^m+\alpha^m\beta^n)-(\alpha^s\beta^t+\alpha^t\beta^s)
&=2(\alpha\beta)^n-(\alpha\beta)^{\mu-\Delta}(\alpha^{2\Delta}+\beta^{2\Delta}) \\
&=(\alpha\beta)^{\mu-\Delta}\left[2\alpha^\Delta\beta^\Delta-\alpha^{2\Delta}-\beta^{2\Delta}\right]\le0,
\end{align}
where the last step follows from
$$2\alpha^\Delta\beta^\Delta-\alpha^{2\Delta}-\beta^{2\Delta}
=-(\alpha^\Delta-\beta^\Delta)^2.$$
The sign of the inequality is consistent with the original statement because
$(n,n)\preceq(n+\Delta,n-\Delta)$ (provided $n-\Delta\ge0$).

Comment: Could possibly the _rearrangement_ formula, which I asked about a few days ago, have some bearing on this? It looks a _kind-of similarish_ thing.

Comment: @AmbretteOrrisey never heard of it. Link?

Comment: How do you link to another post? Or I could give the Wikipedia link. I"ll do _that_ anyway. But I've not been doing this long ... please tell me how to link to another post.

Comment: I'm using an _app_. I'm beginning to think theae _apps_ are very deficient in many ways. It doean't display the link. Hang on ... I'll sort both one way or another.

Comment: Sum of Itemwise Products of Two Sets of Real Numbers.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rearrangement_inequality

Comment: @AmbretteOrrisey that is an interesting inequality, I wasn't aware of it, thanks. I can use it to write $\alpha^n\beta^m+\alpha^m\beta^n\le(\alpha\beta)^n+(\alpha\beta)^m$, but I don't see how to use it together with the majorization assumption

Comment: I didn't have a thorough lead. I'm glad you found it interesting in its own right ... but I don't have _substantial_ reason to believe that it has a bearing on your question - I was just browsing the question & thought "that has a certain superficial similarity". But if you _can_ use it - great! I made a good conjecture on spur-of-moment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inequality you are interested in is wrong. To see this, take $m=3, n=1, s=t=2$. Then it is easy to see that the following inequality $\alpha^3\beta + \alpha \beta^3 \leq 2 \alpha^2 \beta^2$ does not hold.

In fact, it must have an opposite sign. In this case it is a particular case of a powerful [Muirhead's inequality.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muirhead%27s_inequality)

Let $a = (a_1,\dots, a_n)$ and $x=(x_1,\dots, x_n)$ be real nonnegative numbers. Define a symmetric polynomial $a\mapsto\Phi(a)$ with variables $x_1,\dots, x_n$ to be an average of all possible terms $x_{\sigma_1}^{a_1}...x_{\sigma_n}^{a_n}$ over all possible permutations $\sigma $ of ${1,\dots, n}$. In other words, it is 
$$\Phi (a) = \frac{1}{n!}\sum_{\sigma}x_{\sigma_1}^{a_1}...x_{\sigma_n}^{a_n}.$$

For example, $\Phi(3,2) = \frac 1 2 (x_1^3x_2^2 + x_1^2x_2^3)$, $\Phi(3,2,0) = \frac 1 6 (x_1^3x_2^2 + x_1^3 x_3^2 + x_1^2x_2^3+x_1^2x_3^3 + x_2^3x_3^2+x_2^2x_3^3)$.

Then Muirhead's inequality says that if $a$ majorizes $b$, then $\Phi(a)\geq \Phi(b)$.

In your case $\Phi(m,n) = \frac 1 2 (\alpha^m \beta^n +\alpha^n \beta^m)$ and similarly for $\Phi(s,t)$. Now since $(n,m)$ majorizes $(s,t)$, then $\Phi (n,m)\geq \Phi(s,t)$.

The generalization works in the same way.

Comment: ah, you are totally right! I actually did write it correctly in the first version of the post, then for some reason convinced myself it was in the other direction. I see my proofs were in the right direction nonetheless though. This is exactly what I was hoping for, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually figured out how to prove the simple case, though I'm not sure how to generalize the idea to the more general one.

The main point is to "parametrize" $m,n,s,t$ via their averages, which the assumption $n+m=s+t$ implies must be equal:
\begin{align}
n&=\mu+\Delta,\\
m&=\mu-\Delta,\\
s&=\mu+\delta,\\
t&=\mu-\delta.
\end{align}
With these definitions, $(n,m)\succeq(s,t)$ is equivalent to $\Delta\ge\delta$.

With these definitions we have
\begin{align}
C\equiv (\alpha^n\beta^m+\alpha^m\beta^n)-(\alpha^t\beta^s+\alpha^s\beta^t)
=(\alpha\beta)^{\mu}\left[
(\alpha/\beta)^{\Delta} +
(\alpha/\beta)^{-\Delta} -
(\alpha/\beta)^{\delta} -
(\alpha/\beta)^{-\delta}
\right].
\end{align}
Let me now define $\gamma\equiv\alpha/\beta$ for notational convenience. After some algebraic manipulation we get to
$$C=(\alpha\beta)^\mu\gamma^{-\Delta}(1-\gamma^{\Delta-\delta})(1-\gamma^{\Delta+\delta}).$$
It then follows that for $\Delta\ge\delta$ we have $C\ge0$.

The problem with this is that it relies to a "parametrisation" of $n,m,s,t$, which is likely hard to do in a more general case with sequences with more than two numbers.